# Casting to specific type from a generic type

Tags: ios, swift, generics, codable, decodable

I want to cast  to a specific class how can I achieve this?

```
     public class  func parseResponse<T:Decodable>(className:T.Type, response:[String: AnyObject],myid:String,index : Int)->(Bool,T?)
    {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: response) else {
            return (false,nil)
        }

        if myid.count > 0 {
//            let clas1 = NSClassFromString(String(describing: T.Type.self))!
            let obj = T.self as! BaseResponse
            print(String(describing: T.self))

            obj.setKeys(myid: myid, index: index)

        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let object = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            return (true,object)
        }
        catch {

            return (false,nil)
        }
    }
```

I have this method where it is crashing at `let obj = T.self as! BaseResponse` this line saying that it cannot be type cast.

Comment: because your T is Decodable, not BaseResponse

Comment: what is BaseResponse? it obviously can't convert whatever T is at the time to Baseresponse

Comment: What is the need to typecast here? Also the code you added is unclear. The line `let obj = T.self as! BaseResponse` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `let obj = T.self as! BaseResponse` doesn't make much sense. You're trying to create an object by casting a class into another class, when you should be trying to cast an instance of a class into another class.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this algorithm to work, you need `T` to be both `Decodable` and a subtype of `BaseResponse`. Since that's the case, you should say so in your signature.

```
public class func parseResponse<T>(...) -> (Bool,T?)
    where T: BaseResponse & Decodable
```

With that, there's no need to cast anything. Your code hints that `BaseResponse` has a class-level method `setKeys`, so you can just call it on `T` (which you now know to be a subtype of BaseResponse):

```
T.setKeys(...)
```

On an unrelated note `(Bool, T?)` is a very strange return type for this usage. The optionality of `T` already provides everything the Bool is doing, much more cleanly.